# Windows Above Taskbar

Tags: java, taskbar

Are there any ways to allow a window to remain above the taskbar? The window in question is only 16x16 pixels so a full screen window is not what I am seeking here.

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do?

Comment: Actually I'm trying to place a window over a TrayIcon to act as a drop target.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a notification area (system tray) icon, which is a 16 pixel square.

[Use the `TrayIcon` class](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/systemtray/).

Comment: Nah. I mean an actual window e.g. JFrame, JDialog, etc. I mean I have my own hacked out way of doing this but I was hoping for a more "official" way. I just haven't found anything like it.